# COGNOS Report: COUNT IF

Tags: cognos, report-studio

I am not sure how to go about creating a custom field to count instances given a condition.

---

I have a field, `ID`, that exists in two formats:

1. `A#####`
2. `B#####`

I would like to create two columns (one for `A` and one for `B`) and count instances by month. Something like `COUNTIF ID STARTS WITH A` for the first column resulting in something like below. Right now I can only create a table with the total count.

```
+-------+------+------+
| Month | ID A | ID B |
+-------+------+------+
| Jan   | 100  | 10   |
+-------+------+------+
| Feb   | 130  | 13   |
+-------+------+------+
| Mar   | 90   | 12   |
+-------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Define **ID A** as...

```
CASE
  WHEN ID LIKE 'A%' THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

...and set the *Default aggregation* property to *Total*.
Do the same for **ID B**.

Comment: In the Query Item expression for the Query Item named ID A.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I misunderstood the requirement,  but you maybe able to spin the list into crosstab using the section off the toolbar,  your measure value would be count(ID).

Comment: This is also a good answer.  It all depends on your requirements for output formats, downstream data usability, and additional report features.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- Query 1 to count A  , filtering by substring(ID,1,1) = 'A'
- Query 2 to count B  , filtering by substring(ID,1,1) = 'B'
- Join Query 1 and Query 2 by Year/Month
- List by Month with Count A and Count B

Comment: This solution seems a bit complicated.  But if you go that way, you may want to use ID starts with 'A' and let Cognos worry about the actual SQL that's sent to the database server.